# Check jar file is corrupted or not in php?

Tags: java, php, jar

I am executing jar file through php using function exec();

However i need to check whether jar file corrupted or not using php function.

Comment: If the integrity of your JAR files is that important to you, consider using [signed JAR files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/signing.html), then using `jarsigner -verify myjar.jar` to verify the signature

Comment: If you are just worried about file consistency issues, you might as well "just store" md5sums somewhere and compare those. But I agree, if you really care, then *signing* might be the better approach!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for corrupted jar using zip because the jar file is a zipped file, so this will give you an idea:

```
$myfile = '/my/jar/file.jar';

$zip = new ZipArchive();
$res = $zip->open($myfile, ZipArchive::CHECKCONS);
if ($res !== TRUE) {
    switch($res) {
        case ZipArchive::ER_NOZIP:
            die('not a zip archive');
        case ZipArchive::ER_INCONS :
            die('consistency check failed');
        case ZipArchive::ER_CRC :
            die('checksum failed');
        default:
            die('error ' . $res);
    }
}
```

For working with zip files you will need to install the [php zip extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php)